# Laptop charger with broken ground prong

Tags: power-supply, ground

I have an old house (1927) that has been completely renovated, but all the plugs in the living room are 2 pronged.  I have a charger that had the ground prong broken off.  I want to know if it's bad on my laptop or if it's a fire danger to my house.  One I'm willing to risk, one I'm not...

Comment: This questions looks like general reference. Have you searched on [Google][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=pt-BR&safe=off&biw=1366&bih=639&sclient=psy-ab&q=laptop%20charger%20without%20ground&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=a2e7587644b4de20&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.

Comment: I did a google search but most results are forum posts on computer forums that say "it will work".  I would prefer specifics on whether or not it is safe for my old house from qualified electrical engineers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the lack of a safety ground connection is not a danger either to your laptop or to your house ... unless your laptop was going to catch fire anyway for other reasons, but in that case, the ground connection woudn't have made any difference.

But considering your house's wiring generally, for additional peace of mind, you might consider installing ground-fault circuit breakers and/or arc-fault circuit breakers in your breaker box ... assuming, of course, that you have a breaker box and not a fusebox to begin with. However, beware of nuisance trips with these breakers, which may be an indication that the wiring is in generally poor shape and needs to be upgraded.

Comment: The house was completely renovated this year.  It does have a breaker box and given the old wiring and the guys attention to detail I'll go ahead and assume (yeah) that they are ground-fault until I can get a knowledgeable friend out to look at it.  Thank you for the insight and peace of mind!